# How to stop transforms in a CSS transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have set a CSS transition like

```
 transition: all 2s
```

Then I apply a CSS to change the transform like:

```
 transform: rotate(20deg);
```

Transition starts.

**I want to stop it midway and have it stay there so I can then apply some other JS on it that is application dependent... what that is post-pausing is  irrelevant to the question** To test, I use:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
   ...
 }, 1000);
```

One crude way to stop the transition is to set CSS display to 'none'.
Setting transform to 'none' or empty string does not work. The transition goes to the end for transform. Another trick of resetting the CSS to the current one,  works for other properties but not for transforms. Setting transition property to none or empty string also does not stop the transition's transform.

Surely there must be some way.

Any suggestion? Preferrably in JQuery
**I do not want to use animation.**

Comment: stop and get back ? or stop and stay ?

Comment: What if you disable transition?

Comment: @ArthurGuiot If you mean setting transition CSS property to 'none' or empty string, I tried that... See question.

Comment: @Tenabu Afif  Actually you can stop it midway with respect to all other CSS transitions by simply reverting these properties to the current. Trick I learned on some post/blog as in $(selector).css('opacity', $(selector).css('opacity;))  This will stop the opacity transition and works for other CSS properties too but it does not work for transforms for some reason.

Comment: @Sam check my answer below, i update it with this trick and it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using animation where you can easily manage the state:

```js
$('button').eq(0).click(function() {
  $('.box').css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
});
$('button').eq(1).click(function() {
  $('.box').css('animation', 'none');
});
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  animation: anime 10s forwards;
}

@keyframes anime {
  to {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
</div>
<button>Stop</button>
<button>Reset</button>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a way that you can try with transition:

```js
$('button').eq(0).click(function() {
  $('.box').addClass('rotate');
});
$('button').eq(1).click(function() {
  var e = $('.box').css('transform'); // get the current state
  $('.box').css('transform', e); //apply inline style to override the one defined in the class
});
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  transition: all 10s;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
</div>
<button>start</button>
<button>stop</button>
```

Comment: Animations do not stop if display is set to none. That was one reason... Also, transitions are more JS friendly?

Comment: @Sam yes they don't stop with none ... they stop with another property like you can see

Comment: Right o! I will check what I was doing wrong or differently. If it works, I will accept your answer. The only thing that I was doing differently is adding transform property directly as CSS on the element and not as class. Let me see if there is an issue there...

Comment: @Sam if you are adding directly, it the issue then ... as it's already inline so you are getting this value which the final one

Comment: I am adding as $(selector).css('transform','...');  Is that the issue? It works for opacity, width, etc.

Comment: @Sam it may work, but it depend on how you do it ... can you show me a full code where it's not working ? so we can see the issue

Comment: I had deleted the code but retyped it and it works. Must be some typo. If there is an issue, I will comment later but in the next two hours. Accepting your answer. THANKS  for the follow up.